# Validate multiple input in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter-4

**This is the code in my controller:**

```
$fields = array(
    "user_id[]" => "required"
);

print_r($this->request->getPost("user_id"));

$validate = $this->validate($fields);

if (!$validate) {
    $validation = \Config\Services::validation();
    $message = $validation->getErrors();
    echo json_encode($message);
    exit();
}
```

**I'm getting this output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 17
)
{"user_id[]":"The user_id[] field is required."}
```

Why it's showing error when there has values?

Looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try testing  "user_id.0" => "required" and see if this validation works for you ?

Comment: @DhavalChheda, it's not marking as required then. I mean if nothing posted, it's not showing error.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML form

Comment: Can you var dump and show what you have passed with the modification of the code? Also you don't need $validation = \Config\Services::validation(); in your controller. You have to use $this->validator->getErrors() since Validator is already attached to the instance of Controller.

Comment: Also one issue is this particular line : $final_fields[$field] = $validate; . In CI4, Vaidator key is supposed to be string and arrays are represented with a dot parameter. So instead of $final_fields[$field] you have to do following: $final_fields.$field and this should be a string such as  "user_id.0" then only the validator will be able to function properly. Refer : https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html?highlight=validator

Comment: Got a solution. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution from CI forum.

Instead of this,

```
$fields = array(
    "user_id[]" => "required"
);
```

Write:

```
$fields = array(
    "user_id.*" => "required"
);
```